# "# more to go" notification text (when typing comments) is not descriptive enough

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign

I went to leave a comment on a post just now and had the message "5 more to go". It took me a little while to understand what it was referring to but realised it meant characters after a few minutes. Perhaps this could be made clearer? Maybe something like "Your comment is too short. * more to go"

Edit: I've just noticed that before you start typing it says 'add at least 15 chars", I didn't see that when I'd started typing. Not sure if this is enough or if it need to be clearer. Could just be a case of PEBKAC!

Answer (score 2):

Well, actually it says

> enter at least 15 characters

before you type anything in the comment textbox, and then

> 14 more to go...

after you've typed the first character. It seems fairly clear to me; I've never heard this request before.